# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNBootSplash' could not be found

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I had tried few times with the guided articles still hit this error whenever I try to import into App.js > `import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';` > https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash

- Already install > react-native-bootsplash
- Not really need to manually link as react native version 0.73.6
- issued command to generate based on icon.png
- updated styles.xml
- updated AndroidManifest.xml
- updated MainActivity.kt

I had tried clean and new project with all the steps but still hit error.
I hope it will work with splash screen